# How to implement own data storage backend for an PreferenceActivity

Tags: java, android, storage, backend, preferenceactivity

In my application I retrieve data via bluetooth from another device and store this data into a (parcelable) class. I like the user to be able to change the data via an PreferenceActivity. The communication works and the PreferencesScreens are built.

I tried to assign my object to every Preference and overwrite the getPersistedString(),... functions to store the data. This attempt wasn't successfull. Do I have to implement a SharedPreferences class? Or what is the correct way to handle this problem ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved the problem was to register a `OnPreferenceChangeListener` on every `Preference` and do `setPersistent(false)`. Then I can persist the data in the `OnPreferenceChangeListener` to my backend.